# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'controls')

Tags: javascript, angular

I am getting this error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'controls' of undefined".it isnt my code so im trying to understand where the error comes from.
here is my html page:

```
    <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                  <h5 class="card-title"><strong> {{editMode?"Modifier Terminal": "Nouveau Terminal"}} </strong></h5>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body" *ngIf="form">
                  <form class="form-horizontal row" [formGroup]="form">
    
                      
                          <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                              <mat-label>Station</mat-label>
                              <mat-select formControlName="IdStation"  (selectionChange)="geTpeDisponibleByStation($event.value)" required placeholder="Station">
                                <mat-option  value="" disabled > -choisir-</mat-option>

                                <mat-option *ngFor="let item of stations" value="{{item.idStation}}" > {{item.nom}} </mat-option>

                              </mat-select>
                              <mat-error >ce champ est obligatoire</mat-error>    

                            </mat-form-field>&nbsp;
                            <!-- (selectionChange)="filtreStations()"  -->
                          </div>

                          <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                              <mat-label>Numéro de série</mat-label>
                              <mat-select formControlName="SerialNumber" required placeholder="Numéro de série" >
                                <mat-option *ngFor="let item of tpes"  value="{{item.serialNumber}}" required>{{ item.serialNumber }} </mat-option>
                              </mat-select>
                              <mat-error *ngIf="form.get('SerialNumber').hasError('required')">Ce champ est obligatoire</mat-error>
                            </mat-form-field>&nbsp;
                          </div>


                          <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                              <mat-label>Id Terminal</mat-label>
                              <input matInput  formControlName="IdTerminal"  required placeholder="Id Terminal">
                              <mat-error *ngIf="form.get('IdTerminal').hasError('maxlength')">L'Id terminal doit contenir au maximum 12 chiffres</mat-error>                            </mat-form-field>&nbsp;
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-sm-6">


                            <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                              <mat-label>Désignation</mat-label>
                              <input matInput formControlName="Designation"  required placeholder="Designation">
                              <mat-error >{{f.Designation.errors?.required?'ce champ est obligatoire' : 'la Désignation doit contenir au maximum 16 caractères alphanumérique' }}</mat-error>    
                            </mat-form-field>&nbsp;
                   
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-sm-6">


                            <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                              <mat-label>Numéro de téléphone</mat-label>
                              <input matInput formControlName="telephone" required placeholder="Téléphone" pattern="[1-9][0-9]{7}">
                              <mat-error >{{f.telephone.errors?.required?'ce champ est obligatoire' : 'le Numéro de téléphone doit contenir 8 chiffres' }}</mat-error>    
                            </mat-form-field>&nbsp;
                     
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-sm-6" *ngIf="editMode">


                            <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                              <mat-label>Id Bancaire</mat-label>
                              <input matInput formControlName="IdBancaire"  placeholder=" Id Bancaire">
                              <mat-error >ce champ est obligatoire</mat-error>    
                            </mat-form-field>&nbsp;
                     
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-sm-6" *ngIf="editMode">


                            <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                              <mat-label>Code Responsable</mat-label>
                              <input matInput formControlName="CodeResponsable"  placeholder=" Code Responsable">
                              <mat-error >ce champ est obligatoire</mat-error>    
                            </mat-form-field>&nbsp;
                     
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                              <mat-checkbox matInput formControlName="EtatTerminal">Actif</mat-checkbox>&nbsp;
                      
                              <mat-checkbox matInput formControlName="WithBalance"> Afficher solde</mat-checkbox>&nbsp;

                            
                        </div>
                      
          </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-12 text-right">
                            <!-- <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-ladda" data-style="expand-left" style="margin-right:20px; color: rgb(42, 42, 44);" [routerLink]="[ '/tpe/list']">
                              <i class="fa fa-undo"></i>  Annuler
                          </a> -->
                          <button class="btn btn-success btn-ladda" data-style="expand-left" [ladda]='isLoading'(click)="checkAndSave()">
                            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>  {{editMode?"Modifier ": "Ajouter"}}
                          </button>  </div> </form>  </div> </div>
```

Here is my .ts page

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { ToasterService } from 'angular2-toaster';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { PorteurService } from 'app/services/porteur.service';
import { ClientService } from 'app/services/client.service';
import { TerminalService } from 'app/services/terminal.service';
import { AffilService } from 'app/services/affil.service';
import { PointService } from 'app/services/point.service';
import { TpeService } from 'app/services/tpe.service';
import { AffilieService } from 'app/services/affilie.service';
import { StationsService } from 'app/services/stations.service';
import { Console, log } from 'console';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-terminal',
  templateUrl: './add-terminal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-terminal.component.scss']
})
export class AddTerminalComponent implements OnInit {
  form: FormGroup;
  submitted: boolean;
  isLoading: boolean = false;
  oldTerminal: any ; 
  affils: any = [];
  points: any = [];
  tpes: any = [];
  tpesAllAvailables: any = [];

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,

    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private toasterService: ToasterService,
    private router: Router,
    private stationsService:StationsService,
    private terminalService:TerminalService ,
    private tpeService:TpeService
  ) { }

  clients: any = [];
  FiltredStation: any = [];
  stations: any = [];
  filtredStation: any;
  editMode = false;
  model = {
    idTerminal: '', // Ensure this matches the property names used in your form controls
    idAffilie: '',
    idStation: '',
    serialNumber: '',
    idBancaire: '',
    etatTerminal: '',
    dateCreation: '',
    confVersion: '',
    binaryVersion: '',
    withBalance: '',
    batchNumber: '',
    sequenceNumber: '',
    datePremiereOp: '',
    designation: '',
    codeResponsable: '',
    statutReservation: '',
    telephone: '',
    dateStatutReservation: ''
  };
  
 ngOnInit() {
  // Check if editing mode or adding mode
  if (this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')) {
    // edit
    this.editMode = true;
    this.getTerminalById(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'));
  } else {
    // add
    this.editMode = false;
    this.createform(this.model);
  }

  // Initialize form controls
  this.form = this.fb.group({
    IdTerminal: new FormControl("", [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(12)]),
    IdAffilie: new FormControl(""),
    IdStation: new FormControl("", Validators.required),
    SerialNumber: new FormControl("", Validators.required),
    IdBancaire: new FormControl(""),
    EtatTerminal: new FormControl(""),
    DateCreation: new FormControl(""),
    ConfVersion: new FormControl(""),
    BinaryVersion: new FormControl(""),
    WithBalance: new FormControl(""),
    BatchNumber: new FormControl(""),
    SequenceNumber: new FormControl(""),
    DatePremiereOp: new FormControl(""),
    Designation: new FormControl("", [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(16)]),
    CodeResponsable: new FormControl(""),
    StatutReservation: new FormControl(""),
    telephone: new FormControl(""),
    DateStatutReservation: new FormControl("")
  });

  // Disable specific form controls based on editMode
  if (this.editMode) {
    this.form.get('IdTerminal').disable();
    this.form.get('telephone').disable();
  }

  this.getStation();
}





  getTerminalById(id){

    this.terminalService.get(id).subscribe((resp:any) => {
this.createform(resp)
        },
    (err) => {
    
  });
  }


  getStation(){
    
    this.stationsService.List().subscribe((resp:any) => {
      this.stations=resp
        },
    (err) => {
    
  });
  }

  createform(model){
    this.geTpeDisponibleByStation(model.idStation)
    this.form.controls['IdTerminal'].setValue(model.idTerminal);
    this.form.controls['IdAffilie'].setValue(model.idAffilie);
    this.form.controls['IdStation'].setValue(model.idStation);
    this.form.controls['SerialNumber'].setValue(model.serialNumber);
    this.form.controls['IdBancaire'].setValue(model.idBancaire);
    this.form.controls['EtatTerminal'].setValue(model.etatTerminal);
    this.form.controls['DateCreation'].setValue(model.dateCreation);
    this.form.controls['ConfVersion'].setValue(model.confVersion);
    this.form.controls['BinaryVersion'].setValue(model.binaryVersion);
    this.form.controls['WithBalance'].setValue(model.withBalance);
    this.form.controls['BatchNumber'].setValue(model.batchNumber);
    this.form.controls['SequenceNumber'].setValue(model.sequenceNumber);
    this.form.controls['DatePremiereOp'].setValue(model.datePremiereOp);

    this.form.controls['Designation'].setValue(model.designation);
    this.form.controls['CodeResponsable'].setValue(model.codeResponsable);
    this.form.controls['StatutReservation'].setValue(model.statutReservation);
    this.form.controls['telephone'].setValue(model.statutReservation);
    this.form.controls['DateStatutReservation'].setValue(model.dateStatutReservation);
      // this.form = this.fb.group({
      //   IdTerminal : [{  value:model.idTerminal,disabled : this.editMode}, [ Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(12)  ]] ,
        
      //   IdAffilie : [ model.idAffilie, ],
      //   IdStation :[model.idStation, Validators.required],
      //   SerialNumber : [ model.serialNumber,Validators.required],
      //   IdBancaire : [ model.idBancaire,],
      //   EtatTerminal : [ model.etatTerminal,],
      //   DateCreation : [ model.dateCreation,],
      //   ConfVersion : [ model.confVersion,],
      //   BinaryVersion : [ model.binaryVersion,],
      //   WithBalance : [ model.withBalance,],
      //   BatchNumber : [ model.batchNumber,],
      //   SequenceNumber : [ model.sequenceNumber,],
      //   DatePremiereOp : [ model.datePremiereOp,],
      //   Designation : [ model.designation,[ Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(16) ]],
      //   CodeResponsable : [ model.codeResponsable,],
      //   StatutReservation : [ model.statutReservation,],
      //   telephone: [ {value :model.telephone, disabled:this.editMode},],

      //   DateStatutReservation : [ model.dateStatutReservation,]

      // })
  }

  checkAndSave() {
    this.submitted = true;

    if (!this.form.valid)
      return false
      // console.log(this.stations.find(x=>x.idStation==this.form.value.IdStation).idAffilie)
      this.form.controls.IdAffilie.setValue(this.stations.find(x=>x.idStation==this.form.value.IdStation).idAffilie)
                                                                                             
    let form = this.form.getRawValue();
 
    form.EtatTerminal == true ? form.EtatTerminal = 1 : form.EtatTerminal = 0;
    form.WithBalance == true ? form.WithBalance = 1 : form.WithBalance = 0;

    form.StatutReservation == true ? form.StatutReservation = 1 : form.StatutReservation = 0;
    this.isLoading = !this.isLoading;
    // console.log(form)
    if(!this.editMode){
  this.terminalService.add(form).subscribe((resp: any) => {
    this.isLoading = !this.isLoading;
    if (resp.resultCode == 0) {
      this.router.navigate(['/Terminal/list'])
      if(!this.editMode)
      this.toasterService.pop('success', '', 'Le terminal a été créé avec succés');
      else
      this.toasterService.pop('success', '', 'Le terminal a été modifié avec succés');

    } else if (resp.resultCode == 1) {
      this.toasterService.pop('error', '', 'Id terminal déja exist');
      
    }
 else {
      this.toasterService.pop('error', '', 'Une erreur est survenue');

    }

  },
    () => {
      this.isLoading = !this.isLoading;

      this.toasterService.pop('error', '', 'Une erreur est survenue');
    });
}
else {
  this.terminalService.update(form.IdTerminal, form).subscribe((resp: any) => {
    this.isLoading = !this.isLoading;
    if (resp.resultCode == 0) {
      //console.log("this.respTer",resp);
      //this.oldTerminal = resp.oldTerminal;
      //console.log("this.oldTerminal",this.oldTerminal);
      
      this.router.navigate(['/Terminal/list'])
      this.toasterService.pop('success', '', 'Le terminal a été modifié avec succés');
    } else {
      this.toasterService.pop('error', '', 'Une erreur est survenue');

    }


  },
    () => {
      this.isLoading = !this.isLoading;

      this.toasterService.pop('error', '', 'Une erreur est survenue');
    });
}
   
  }// end checkAndSave

  

  geTpeDisponibleByStation(event:any){
    //console.log(event);
    
    this.form.controls['SerialNumber'].setValue("");
    this.tpeService.geTpeDisponibleByStation(event).subscribe((resp:any) => {
      this.tpes=resp
      
        },
    (err) => {
    
  });
  }


   get f() { return this.form.controls; } 

}// end class
```

and this is the console error :

```
script.js:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'controls')
at i.geTpeDisponibleByStation (main.js:1:1345437)
at i.createform (main.js:1:1343054)
at i.ngOnInit (main.js:1:1342184)
at nC (main.js:1:3178196)
at E0 (main.js:1:3178017)
at Md (main.js:1:3177737)
at Ra (main.js:1:3229172)
at oE (main.js:1:3229469)
at Ra (main.js:1:3229494)
at kb (main.js:1:3235948)
```

I don't get why I am getting that error?, im only having the title show on the page.

Comment: could you please (temporarily) disable angular's minification, so that the error will actually give you the referene to the right file and the right codeline? as of now, we only know that somewhere in your code the property `controls` is not defined, and there are many occurrences of `this.form.controls` in your code.

Comment: You need call to your function `geTpeDisponibleByStation` **after** create the form

Answer (score 0):

The initialize form controls is incorrect in ngOnit.

Before calling your this.form variable, you must assign it to avoid : TypeError: Cannot read property 'controls' of undefined error.

Define your form like :

```
     ngOnInit() {
        // Initialize form controls
        this.form = this.fb.group({
          IdTerminal: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(12)]),
          IdAffilie: new FormControl(''),
          IdStation: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
          SerialNumber: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
          IdBancaire: new FormControl(''),
          EtatTerminal: new FormControl(''),
          DateCreation: new FormControl(''),
          ConfVersion: new FormControl(''),
          BinaryVersion: new FormControl(''),
          WithBalance: new FormControl(''),
          BatchNumber: new FormControl(''),
          SequenceNumber: new FormControl(''),
          DatePremiereOp: new FormControl(''),
          Designation: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(16)]),
          CodeResponsable: new FormControl(''),
          StatutReservation: new FormControl(''),
          telephone: new FormControl(''),
          DateStatutReservation: new FormControl(''),
        });
.......
```